# Definition: Negligible compared to unity

Tags: slope

It is often stated that if the slope or rotation of a point or an object is small then the derivative is negligible compared to unity. What does it mean? What is meant here by "unity"?

Comment: Unity = the number 1.

Comment: But if we discuss rotation of the point of the deformed body what this unity means? 1 degree, 1 radian or a slope of 1?

Comment: The derivative is the slope, so if you compare the derivative to 1, it means you're comparing it to a slope of 1.